# How to handle columns mixed with datetime.time and timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timestamp

I would like to have a dataframe that all columns in the `datetime.time` format. But my original dataframe is like

```
        Moorabbin            Mordialloc  Aspendale            Edithvale            Chelsea          
    0   04:48:00             05:00:00    05:05:00             05:10:00             05:15:00 
    1   06:45:00             06:57:00    07:02:00             07:07:00             07:12:00
    2   1900-01-01 00:48:00  NaN         1900-01-01 01:03:00  1900-01-01 01:08:00  1900-01-01 01:13:00  
    3   05:09:00             NaN         NaN                  05:36:00             05:41:00
```

What I would like to get is

```
        Moorabbin            Mordialloc  Aspendale            Edithvale            Chelsea          
    0   04:48:00             05:00:00    05:05:00             05:10:00             05:15:00     
    1   06:45:00             06:57:00    07:02:00             07:07:00             07:12:00
    2   00:48:00             NaN         01:03:00             01:08:00             01:13:00 
    3   05:09:00             NaN         NaN                  05:36:00             05:41:00
```

The datatypes of those values are

```
> type(test_result.iloc[0,0])
datetime.time
> type(test_result.iloc[2,0])
pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp
```

I tried `to_datetime(format= "%H:%M:%S", error = "coerce")`, `datetime.strptime(test_result['Moorabbin'],"%H:%M:%S").time()` and `test_result.astype('datetime64[ns]', copy=True, errors='ignore')`, but nothing worked. Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

one approach would be as follows.
Make sure the type is 'object', you can convert it to datetime after you have reduced the data to your required 'length.

Then do `df_new = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(' ').str[-1], axis=1)`

**Input**

```
  Moorabbin     Mordialloc  Aspendale   Edithvale   Chelsea
0   4:48:00     5:00:00     5:05:00     5:10:00     5:15:00
1   6:45:00     6:57:00     7:02:00     7:07:00     7:12:00
2   1/1/1900 0:48:00    NaN     1/1/1900 1:03:00    1/1/1900 1:08:00    1/1/1900 1:13:00
3   5:09:00     NaN     NaN     5:36:00     5:41:00
```

**output** (df_new)

```
  Moorabbin     Mordialloc  Aspendale   Edithvale   Chelsea
0   4:48:00     5:00:00     5:05:00     5:10:00     5:15:00
1   6:45:00     6:57:00     7:02:00     7:07:00     7:12:00
2   0:48:00     NaN         1:03:00     1:08:00     1:13:00
3   5:09:00     NaN             NaN     5:36:00     5:41:00
```

**Note** The result is object & not dateime object but you can convert it to datetime object using `pd.to_datetime` on these columns.